# How to set the version of a DLL within progam code?

Tags: c++, dll, version

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 for a C++ DLL project and I would like to set the version of the compiled DLL within my program code.

How is this possible?

Thanks for your help

Comment: The best solution could be to use a project or a pre-build command to run an SVN or info in a bash script to extract version info string. And fill the project VERSION field with the value you get ! But that mecanism should be part of your build system.

Comment: @alexbuisson: A **bash** script will be somewhat of a challenge in a Visual Studio (Windows) environment.

Comment: @MSalters it can be a **bash** script (i.e in My company every in every component, product we develop we always include a project called GetVersion and that project run a pre-build like "sh GenerateSvnVersion.sh $(OutDir)" ) if Cygwin is present. But if you prefer BATCH or PowerShell... you can use whatever language you want to parse your Source Control info!!!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, not possible. The linker flag `/VERSION` cannot be set via `#pragma comment(linker)` from within your source code, you'll have to do this from your project file instead.